# Are there any JavaScript libraries or sample code for google cloud pub/sub?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-pubsub

I am evaluating google cloud pub/sub to send messaging to my JavaScript client application (ionic, angular app). I couldn’t find any sample code for subscribing pub/sub messaging in JavaScript.

JFYI: I have nodejs on server-side.

Comment: Now they have [official client library for nodejs](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub).

Answer (score 6):

There is no client library provided for Javascript. If you want to access messages from Javascript, you will have to make [HTTP pull requests](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull).  In order to make these requests, they will need to be authorized. That means you would have to have making [OAuth2 access token requests for a service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#applications) from your client application.

In general, Google Cloud Pub/Sub is not going to be the best way to send messages from a server to client applications that are run by your users unless you have very tight control over who the users are that are accessing the app. Additionally, since there is a [limit of 10,000 subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas) in Google Cloud Pub/Sub, you could only ever have 10,000 users receive the full stream of messages. Instead, you might want to consider [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for this type of use case.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is helpful. I can consider firebase only for realtime messaging, what would be approx monthly charges if I consider 1 million concurrent users and approx 1 million messages per day of 10 kb size per message?

Comment: Also let me clear one thing, I dont want push notification, It should ask user permission to allow notification. it should be inline realtime messaging, if that is the case then do you still think firebase cloud messaging is valid solution?

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging is free. It will require the user to grant permission to allow notifications and I believe it will show notifications if the web app is in the background of the browser, even if you use data messages (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages). Data messages can be up to 4KB. Those facts might make Firebase Cloud Messaging a less ideal choice for your use case.

Comment: Sorry for misspelled, application should NOT prompt user for permissions. All message should be real-time.